# How do I check if my ssd supports fstrim?

Tags: linux, ssd, trim, fstrim

I'm working with a linux server and wanted to know if there is a way that I can find out that my SSD supports fstrim or not. I tried `hdparm -I /dev/sda`, but it's not available and I can't install it. Is there any other way I can do it? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

I'm also curious to know what happens if I run fstrim on a device that doesn't support trim? Does it result in a no-op?

Answer (score 6):

You may also try 
`lsblk --discard`

Non-zero values under `DISC-GRAN` and `DISC-MAX` indicate trim support.

```
$ lsblk --discard
NAME          DISC-ALN DISC-GRAN DISC-MAX DISC-ZERO
nvme0n1              0      512B       2T         0
├─nvme0n1p1          0      512B       2T         0
├─nvme0n1p2          0      512B       2T         0
├─nvme0n1p3          0      512B       2T         0
└─nvme0n1p4          0      512B       2T         0
  └─cryptswap        0        0B       0B         0
```

Ensure your disk is trim compatible before running `fstrim`.  Running `fstrim` on an SSD that does not provide trim support can result in data loss.  For reference, see the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Solid_state_drive).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
find /sys/devices -name trim -exec head {} +

... 
==> /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/ata3/link3/dev3.0/ata_device/dev3.0/trim <==
unsupported
```

Answer (score -1):

Every SSD made in the past decade supports trim/discard. If it isn't supported, the command should just fail and not do anything. I say "should" because if you really have an SSD without trim it is of such poor branding lineage that the disk firmware quality is an extreme unknown quantity.

Comment: If connected through a raid controller, it may hide this capability. So it is useful to know for sure.